# How to repeat parsing json data using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this code from w3school works like a charm:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>Customers</h1>
    <div id="id01"></div>

    <script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        var out = "<table>";

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td>" +
            arr[i].Name +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].City +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].Country +
            "</td></tr>";
        }
        out += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

but when I repeat the script like this it doesn't work:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>Customers</h1>
    <div id="id01"></div>

    <script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        var out = "<table>";

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td>" +
            arr[i].Name +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].City +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].Country +
            "</td></tr>";
        }
        out += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
    }
    </script>

<h1>Buyers</h1>
    <div id="id02"></div>

    <script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://www.w3schools.com/website/customers_mysql.php";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        var out = "<table>";

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td>" +
            arr[i].Name +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].City +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].Country +
            "</td></tr>";
        }
        out += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("id02").innerHTML = out;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

What variable name  should I change? I did the script once it worked but twice it didn't work.
I tried changing variable but it didn't work
I changed all the variable names.

Comment: What exactly you want can you elaborate

Comment: You can not use same ID again and again on one page but if you are using as a different html then also dt use other ever updated code willoverride the first id only..

Comment: @Kabali — The OP isn't reusing HTML ID values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two scripts exist in the same JS environment. They both create global variables with the same name and interfere with each other.

Wrap each script in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) to create a new scope for each one to operate in.

```
<script>
    (function () {
         // Your code here
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't work because you're executing AJAX call across domains. You can't do an ajax call like that unless you are calling a page on the same domain. There are workarounds, but this is the problem in your case.

Instead create a local file to test your AJAX with.

This is why it works on the w3 Schools site, but not on your own code.

Comment: The endpoint hosted by w3schools supports CORS. This is not the problem.